# jquery selecting dynamically loaded div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got the following jQuery that loads some html into a div when it is hovered over:

```
$("div").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).load('htmlsnippets/divHoverButtons.txt');
    }, 
    function(){
        $("#divHoverButtons").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });

$("#setWidth").click(
    function(){
        $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
```

divHoverButtons.txt contains:

```
<div id="divHoverButtons">
    <div id='setWidth'>Set Width</div>
</div>
```

So, when any div is hovered over, it becomes:

```
<div>
    <div id="divHoverButtons">
        <div id='setWidth'>Set Width</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I then click on the div "setWidth", it doesn't hide it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It does'nt really sound like a great idea to use ajax to load three lines of html everytime an element is moused over? And you should be using the delegated version of on() for this, and probably just keep those three lines of html in a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use `delegate()` because your div #setWidth is not in the DOM when it's loaded

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

```
$("body").delegate("#setWidth", "click", function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Is it possible to reload the DOM, binding the new elements in?

Comment: I don't think so, that's why you have to use delegates to bind events on DOM elements which are not on the DOM yet

Comment: Did you read on the site in your link where it said "delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method" ?